# Using a lambda and compute in web2pyfield

Tags: web2py

i want put False or True according the value row date3 but it put me by default False

```
   Field ('heure','boolean',compute=lambda r: True if r.date3 <= 23 else False)
```

Comment: Your code looks correct, though can be simplified to: `compute=lambda r: r.date3 <= 23` (no need for the ternary because `r.date <= 23` is already a boolean). Are you saying the field is being set to `False` even when the value of `date23` is <= 23? If so, is this happening on insert or update?

Comment: it works now thank you anthony I looked forward to your message you my saves several galley of code several times. So if I understand if for example I have this code Field ('is_public', 'boolean') if I want to compute a another field I have done Field ('result' compute = lambda row : * row.calcul row.maison if row.is_public else row.calcul * 20)

Answer (score 0):

it works now thank you anthony I looked forward to your message you my saves several galley of code several times. So if I understand if for example I have this code

```
Field ('is_public', 'boolean') if I want to compute a another field I have done Field     ('result' compute = lambda row : * row.calcul row.maison if row.is_public else row.calcul * 20)
```